# Animation CPU Spike from Loading.ReadObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The first time I run my game and trigger an Animation, there is a pretty big CPU spike (last one was 153ms) which once investigated, led me to see that it was Unity loading the animations as needed and that was causing it, at least that's what I believe.

I have read around and everyone seems to say that having the assets in the Resources folder and using `Resources.Load("")` would fix it, however I am still running into the issue despite placing that in both `Awake()` and `Start()` methods on various objects. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a specific way for me to load the sprites I need at load and would that stop the CPU spikes?

Answer (score 0):

Ever since unity 4.5.x There is a way to use `Resources.Load("")` in a asynchronous way. This would allow you to prevent/reduce the spike in CPU usage quite a bit. The syntax for this being [Resources.LoadAsync()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html) In combination with a coroutine you should be able to resolve your issue.

If you need more detailed help with this, please include your actual code in your question as well.